# PyQt/Pyside - also return the previous value with valueChanged

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtgui, qtablewidgetitem

I am new to these forums. 
In a QTableWidget I am trying to validate the changed value of the QTableWidgetItem. If the new value is present elsewhere in the table, I need to revert the value back to the previous value. I have thought of using a temporary list but wanted to know if it is possible to have a custom signal or similar which could return the changed value as well as the previous value of the qtablewidgetitem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the reimplementation of this method:

> [void QAbstractItemDelegate::setModelData(QWidget * editor, QAbstractItemModel * model, const QModelIndex & index) const [virtual]](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html#setModelData)
>
> Sets the data for the item at the given index in the model to the contents of the given editor.
>
> The base implementation does nothing. If you want custom editing you will need to reimplement this function.

This would allow you to emit a signal here where a cell changes, both with the previous and current values.

There does not seem to be a convenience signal off-hand in `QTableWidget` for this.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I need to get my hands dirty with custom delegates. :) Will post the code when I am done.